# How to select any url from Iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I have some data from my database.I want to print only url from iframe.

my data:

```
$data="<p style="text-align: justify;">Este foi o anúncio que a Microsoft passou no dia da Super Bowl. Veja como a tecnologia têm melhorado a vida das pessoas.</p>

<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper">
<iframe width="640" height="400" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/qaOvHKG0Tio" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>";
```

Comment: I want to show only www.youtube.com/embed/qaOvHKG0Tio from $data @SatishSharma

Comment: i thing you want to extract only src in your `$data` variable. am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your answer

you should extract the `substring` from `$data` variable like this

```
$data='<p style="text-align: justify;">Este foi o anúncio que a Microsoft passou no dia da Super Bowl. Veja como a tecnologia têm melhorado a vida das pessoas.</p>

<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper">
<iframe width="640" height="400" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/qaOvHKG0Tio" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>';

$from = 'src="';
$to = '"';
$str = getStringBetween($data,$from,$to);
echo $str; // will output : //www.youtube.com/embed/qaOvHKG0Tio
```

**function**

```
 function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to)
    {
        $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
        return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
    }
```